# BTRFS remove directory from snapshot

Tags: snapshot, btrfs

There is the:

```
 btrfs subvolume delete <subvolume>
```

command for deleting snapshots, but is there any solution if you need to delete a single directory from 60 snapshots?

Not possible with rm -rf  it will say Read-only file system.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your snapshot is read only. Try to enable read/write using the following command:

```
btrfs property set -ts /path/to/snapshot ro false
```

Also, double check than when mounting the snapshot it is not mounted in read-only mode (`ro` mount option)